# Create one fragment and reuse it

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have 2 fragments a and b in which there is a container for fragments, I need to place a separate fragment x in these 2 containers so that the nested fragment x is not recreated when switching between fragments a and b, create a singleton from fragment x. Please tell me how can i implement this

Comment: This demand ignores the layout hierarchy. One can't just replace the parent of a child node. You could only have one parent, which has two different appearances, depending which child node it shows.

Answer (score 0):

if i was in this situation, i would modify my design such that x falls outside of a and b. this is because it would be more efficient. because every time you switch the fragments, lets say from a to b, a enters `paused` state and b enters `resumed` state. change of state would need component to act on their widgets which would consume processing power. if x was outside, then no processing is required because it's not re-rendered. if you still want to implement things this way, then make the `data` persistent, not the entire `fragment`. when a fragment is rendered on screen, it's children must also be rendered. there is no other option. you cannot just render a block on screen but expect some of its children to already be rendered on screen before parent has rendered. this is why you'll see `onCreate` passes a `Bundle` param. the param contains all data that required retention and that's why things are able to be rendered the same. it's a good idea to separate **data** from **architecture**. hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, really good solution. My case is that I have a video playing in the webview, and I need it not to reload when I switch to full screen mode

Comment: For this I will refer you to implementing the video playing _as a service_. this might help: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer